# JavaScript function getting called twice on Enter key press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button in my html page

```
<input id="btnLogin" class="loginBtn" type="button" value="Login" title="Login" />
```

I have binded a jquery click event to this button like

```
 $('#btnLogin').click(function () {
    ValidateLogin();
});
```

I'm also checking the enter key press to call the same function `ValidateLogin();` like below

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        ValidateLogin();
    }
});
```

The issue that i'm facing is when the user presses the `tab key` to get in focus over the `Login` button and then press `Enter Key` the `ValidateLogin()` is called twice.How to deal with this situation.

**Note :**  i can't use type="submit" to do a form submit ..since i'm using ajax call on button click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event instead. Your browser is probably firing the `click` event when pressing enter and that is effectively the same as pressing the submit button:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    // Stop the form submitting
    e.preventDefault(); 
    ValidateLogin();
});

function ValidateLogin() {
    $.ajax({
        // ...
    }).done(function(e) {
        if(!e.valid) {
            alert("Invalid Login");
        }
    });
}
```

Second reason, even if your `keypress` was to work correctly, I can press a button by pressing spacebar too.

[Here is a full Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ePX4g/) to demonstrate.

Comment: @techfoobar have a look at this , http://jsfiddle.net/jDzg3/   its not working here...

Comment: @iJay `type="button"` needs to be `type="submit"` if the intent is to submit the form

Comment: well actually i'm using ajax call on button click hence the reason why i have avoided using type="submit"

Comment: @iJay I have updated my answer to reflect your AJAX call. The main line here is `e.preventDefault()` which stops the form from submitting. You are then free to do whatever AJAX you want. The reason I'm pushing `submit()` so hard is that you can never assume the submit function works the same across all browsers/systems

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a form I would prefer to attach event on form elements instead on document.

Use form element like text, textarea etc. on click of enter should submit the form.

```
$('input:text, textarea').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        ValidateLogin();
    }
});
```

In your case event is bubbled from the button to document hence it is called twice.

Comment: Even better would be to add a class to the input controls that would trigger the validation, and then just use the class selector. Otherwise you have to add each form control type to the selector

Comment: @jasonscript agreed :)

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine check this fiddler [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xqCwd/)

```
      <input id="btnLogin" class="loginBtn" type="button" value="Login" title="Login" />

  $('#btnLogin').click(function () {
      //ValidateLogin();
      alert('click');
  });
  $(document).keypress(function (e) {
      if (e.which == 13) {
          //ValidateLogin();
          alert('enter');
      }
      e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Comment: This would prevent the user from entering data into `input` controls because you're calling `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: here the use not need to enter data again and again after pressing enter. because user already entered the username and password, user is pressing the enter for login.